# npm start command returns an error in the cmd

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I want to start my React app, but when I run `npm start`, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Muchendu\Documents\GitHub\Steve-React/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Muchendu\Documents\GitHub\Steve-React\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muchendu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-11T09_26_37_201Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: There is no package.json in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because right after running

```
npx create-react-app <your_app_name>
```

you are trying to run npm start

Instead try switching into your app directory like so:

```
cd <your_app_name>
```

because that is where your package.json will most likely exist and then try running

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

run this command in the terminal inside your project `npm init -y`.
This will generate a package.json in your project.

Otherwise since you are making a react app use the `npx create-react-app your-app-name` this will create all the necessary files for running you application.

What is package.json?
*The package.json file is the heart of any Node project. It records important metadata about a project which is required before publishing to NPM, and also defines functional attributes of a project that npm uses to install dependencies, run scripts, and identify the entry point to our package.*